# How to pass and increment the value of a pointer variable at the same time?

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, binary-tree

Sorry if the question header is vague, but here is the description.

I wanted to check if 2 nodes in a binary tree are cousins. I am calling a function which updates the value of the level as it traverses, and then compares the 2 values to see if they are cousins.

My algorithm may not be correct, but I just want to figure out how to increment the value inside the pointer variable inside the function call.

```
void findLevel(Node *node,Node *nodeToFind, int* l)
{
    if(!node)
        return;
    if(node==nodeToFind)
        return;
    if(node->left)
        findLevel(node->left, nodeToFind, (*l)++); #line 1
    if(node->right)
        findLevel(node->right, nodeToFind, (*l)++);#line 2
    return;
    //(*l)++;                                      #line 3
}

bool ifCousin(Node *root,Node *a,Node *b)
{
    int* l1;
    int* l2;
    *l1=0;
    *l2=0;
    findLevel(root, a, l1);
    findLevel(root, b, l2);
    if(l1==l2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I am getting an error on lines 1 and 2 because the types don't match. 
I could something like line 3 but that would increment the value on each function call. I don't want that.

How can I possibly increment the level as I make the call?

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'void findLevel(Node*, Node*, int*)':
prog.cpp:98:49: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
         findLevel(node->left, nodeToFind, (*l)++);
                                                 ^
prog.cpp:92:6: note:   initializing argument 3 of 'void findLevel(Node*, Node*, int*)'
 void findLevel(Node *node,Node *nodeToFind, int* l){
      ^
prog.cpp:100:50: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
         findLevel(node->right, nodeToFind, (*l)++);
                                                  ^
prog.cpp:92:6: note:   initializing argument 3 of 'void findLevel(Node*, Node*, int*)'
 void findLevel(Node *node,Node *nodeToFind, int* l){
      ^
```

Comment: Why fight it? It's a post increment. Increment after the call.

Comment: Have you considered using a reference? `void findLevel(Node *node,Node *nodeToFind, int& l)`

Comment: @user4581301 I tried with a reference. same issue. Couldn't increment it.

Comment: `int* l1;` followed by `*l1=0;` This is an ill doom. No storage has been assigned to `l1`. You are setting Crom-knows-what to zero and programs hate that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on crack. ++ returns a rvalue.

Comment: @user463035818 I am just figuring out a way to make it happen simultaneously. The error message is clear to me. I can't think of any other way to increment the levels. Line 3 is also not an option.  also, error message added!

Comment: What is the goal of `findLevel`? If you are trying to find how far down the tree a given node is, your algorithm will not work. It could march all the way down the left without finding the node incrementing the whole way, then start marching down the right incrementing more. La la la... and then finally sput uot the count of nodes visited, not the depth of the node in the tree. I think you're better off with pass by value  so you can easily backtrack.

Comment: there is nothing happening "simultaneously". you are putting two things in one line, just dont do that and the problem is gone

Comment: i mean you want to pass the pointer and you want to increment the value that pointer points to. Thats two different things, why do you want to do it the complicated way?

Comment: why do you use a pointer to pass the int anyhow? You have some weird undefined behaviour just because of that. Why not a plain `int` ?

Comment: @user463035818 I am passing a pointer so that in each recursive call I use the same value again and again. Also, I dont want to do it the complicated way. I just cant figure out how to pass and increment for each level.

Comment: you dont need to use a pointer to use the same value again and again, an `int` will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

`(*l)++` dereferences the pointer and then increments the value that was being pointed at. Is that what you really want? If so, then you need to pass `l` as-is on each recursive call to `findLevel()` without incrementing it in the same statement <sup>1</sup>:

```
void findLevel(Node *node, Node *nodeToFind, int* l)
{
    if (!node)
        return;
    if (node == nodeToFind)
        return;
    if (node->left)
    {
        (*l)++; // <-- here
        findLevel(node->left, nodeToFind, l);
    }
    if (node->right)
    {
        (*l)++; // <-- here
        findLevel(node->right, nodeToFind, l);
    }
    return;
}
```

<sup>1: though I'm sure this algorithm is wrong, as @user4581301 explained in comments, but I'm not sure the correct way to fix it.</sup>

And BTW, this code:

```
int* l1;
int* l2;
*l1=0;
*l2=0;
```

Is **undefined behavior**, as you are dereferencing uninitialized pointers.  `ifCousin()` should look more like this instead:

```
bool ifCousin(Node *root, Node *a, Node *b)
{
    int l1 = 0;
    int l2 = 0;
    findLevel(root, a, &l1);
    findLevel(root, b, &l2);
    return (l1 == l2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problem: Increment pointed-at value while calling function with pointer

You cannot do what you want to do without doing way too much work. Worse, what you want to do won't do what I believe you need to do.

The current code, if fixed, will return the number of nodes visited while searching and not the depth of the node in the tree.

## Solution: Do something else

```
int findLevel(Node *node, Node *nodeToFind, int level) // not a pointer
{
    if (!node) // probably redundant You test for NULL before recursing.
               // Add test for NULL before entering and you're done
        return 0; // can't find anything here
    level++; // save a few increments by doing it once here
    if (node == nodeToFind)
        return level; // found it. Return level

    int foundat = 0;
    if (node->left) // check left
        foundat = findLevel(node->left, nodeToFind, level);
    if (foundat == 0 && node->right) // if we need to, check right
        foundat = findLevel(node->right, nodeToFind, level);
    return foundat;
}
```

This counts only the levels, and the level counter is passed by value so the count is easily backtracked by stack-popping as functions return.